# Keep Array value when Sub is looping

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, excel-tables

I currently have this code that finds all files and folders and writes it to a table. The problem is is that is it sometimes slow.

The code below is modified so that it writes to an array but I am having issues passing the array on when the code loops.

Ultimately, I would like the array to pass on to the first sub so that I can transpose it into the table at once.

```
Sub FileAndFolder()

Dim FSOLibrary As Object
Dim FSOFolder As Object
Dim FolderName As String
Dim FilesTbl As ListObject
Set FilesTbl = Range("FilesTbl").ListObject

'Set the folder name to a variable
FolderName = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\"))

'Set the reference to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start
LoopAllFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)

'return TempArray here and paste into table

'Range(FilesTbl.ListColumns("File Name").DataBodyRange(1)) = TempArray

End Sub

Sub LoopAllFolders(FSOFolder As Object)
'Don’t run the following macro, it will be called from the macro above

Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
Dim FSOFile As Object
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim TempArray() As String

'For each subfolder call the macro
For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    LoopAllFolders FSOSubFolder
Next

'For each file, print the name
For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
    FileName = FSOFile.Name
    FolderPath = FSOFile.ParentFolder
          
    If Left(FileName, 2) = "~$" Then GoTo NEXTINLOOP
    ReDim Preserve TempArray(0 To 3, 0 To i)
        
    TempArray(0, i) = FileName
    TempArray(1, i) = FolderPath & "\" & FileName 'file
    TempArray(2, i) = FolderPath 'folder
    TempArray(3, i) = FolderPath & "\" & FileName 'showpath
        
    i = i + 1
NEXTINLOOP:
Next
 
End Sub 'TempArray and i clears here
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to declare a variable at the module level so that the list of folder information is available to all methods in the module, or change 'LoopAllFolders' to a Function so that you can return the information you have collated.

The function below will return a Variant which contains an array of arrays (normally called a jagged array).  You access the jagged array using this nomenclature

```
Varname(x)(y)
```

You will need a variable in the calling method to receive the jagged array

e.g.

```
Dim myFileInfo as Variant
MyFileInfo = LoopAllFolders(FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName))
```

Here is the updated function

```
Public Function LoopAllFolders(FSOFolder As Scripting.FileSystemObject) As Variant
'Don’t run the following macro, it will be called from the macro above

    Dim FileInfo As Scripting.Dictionary: Set myFileInfo = New Scripting.Dictionary

'For each subfolder call the macro

    Dim FSOSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
        LoopAllFolders FSOSubFolder
    Next

    'For each file, print the name
    Dim FSOFile As Scripting.File
    For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

        'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = FSOFile.Name
    
        Dim FolderPath As String
        FolderPath = FSOFile.ParentFolder
          
        If Not Left(FileName, 2) = "~$" Then
    
            myFileInfo.Add Array(FileName, FolderPath & "\" & FileName, FolderPath, FolderPath & "\" & FileName)
        
        End If
    
    Next

    LoopAllFolders = myFileInfo.Items
 
End Function
```

The above code may not be perfect but at least it points you in the right direction.

Based on your question, you might do well by working through a VBA tutorial as functions are fairly fundamental, and if you are unaware of them......

To help you on your journey I'd also recommend installing the fantastic and free RubberDuck addin.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I tweaked it a little and now has more than halved my original code

Answer (score 0):

### Create a List of Files all subfolders of a Folder

- I do not understand what you're doing with `FilesTbl`, so I modified your solution to create a new workbook with the result. Surely you will figure out how to apply it to the table.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FileAndFolder()

    Dim FSOLibrary As Object
    Dim FSOFolder As Object
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim FilesTbl As ListObject
    'Set FilesTbl = Range("FilesTbl").ListObject
    
    'Set the folder name to a variable
    FolderName = Left$(ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\"))
    
    'Set the reference to the FSO Library
    Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim TempArray() As Variant ' ByRef
    
    'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start
    LoopAllFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName), TempArray
    
    'return TempArray here and paste into table
    With Workbooks.Add
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(TempArray, 2), UBound(TempArray))
            .Value = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
        End With
        .Saved = True
    End With
    
    'Range(FilesTbl.ListColumns("File Name").DataBodyRange(1)) = TempArray

End Sub

Sub LoopAllFolders(FSOFolder As Object, ByRef TempArray As Variant)
'Don’t run the following macro, it will be called from the macro above

    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Long
    'Dim TempArray() As String
    
    'For each subfolder call the macro
    For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
        LoopAllFolders FSOSubFolder, TempArray
    Next
    
    'For each file, print the name
    For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files
    
        'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
        FileName = FSOFile.Name
        FolderPath = FSOFile.ParentFolder
              
        If Left(FileName, 2) = "~$" Then GoTo NEXTINLOOP
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve TempArray(1 To 4, 1 To i)
            
        TempArray(1, i) = FileName
        TempArray(2, i) = FolderPath & "\" & FileName 'file
        TempArray(3, i) = FolderPath 'folder
        TempArray(4, i) = FolderPath & "\" & FileName 'showpath
            
NEXTINLOOP:
    Next
 
End Sub 'TempArray and i clears here
```